# Third-Party AWS Login Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to build an app (in Node.JS) that allows a user to see their buckets and objects in S3 from AWS. The user can log in using Facebook. What should I be using to allow the user that logs in access to their resources on my app?

Thanks in advance for any resources you can provide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast and less secure option
1. In the AWS-IAM create a new user called "APPGUEST"
2. In the S3 create bucket called "APPGUEST" and create a subdirectory for each user 
3. Back in IAM create new group policy that should look like this (use the policy generator)
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
                "s3:Get* (list of permissions according your needs and access) *"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::APPGUEST",
                "arn:aws:s3:::APPGUEST/*"
            ]
    }
  ]
}
 in addition you should create a table with the list of users (FB) and their matching directories.
For each user you create a subdirectory in APPGUEST s3 bucket, try to avoid creating bucket for each user since it is limited to 99 buckets by AWS.